# How to click on button and select previous value selected in combo box in Page1 using go back button in Page2 using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF application, i have implemented Page1 which contains button(named as View) and a related ComboBox(will display when the view button is clicked).

After selecting any value in combobox, from Page1 i am navigating to Page2 using

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

In Page2 there is one go back button. when i click on that button page should navigate to Page1. with clicking on the view button and previously selected value in combobox.

but when navigating Page1 from Page2 default button is showing only and combobox is not selecting the value.

can anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

If I follow your explanation then the first thing to try is just to set:

```
KeepAlive="true"
```

On Page1 in the page tag.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.keepalive(v=vs.110).aspx

But note, as it says:
"You should avoid setting KeepAlive to true unless you need to"

Comment: It is not working. In my Page1 i have implemented loaded option to load the list of values from backend. Loaded="data_Load" by default it selects "Select name" when the Page1 is loaded.

Comment: You mean that code is the problem.  Can't you just move that to the initialized event or call the method from the constructor?